# Custom RESTEasy-Validation

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I like to introduce a numeric check / constraintValidator for a Get-Paramter.
It should looks like:

```
@GET
@Path("/{docId}")
@IsNumeric
public SomeThing getSomeThing(@PathParam("docId") String docId) {
    return ...;
}
```

Im am not sure how to implement it. docId should be validated and a BadRequest should be returned when docId is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do any validation for this. JAX-RS allows you to use a regex in the `@Path` expression. So you could just use `@Path("{docId: \\d+}")`. This would not lead to a 400 Bad Request though. Instead, you would get a 404 if it doesn't match. This *should* be what you want though. If it's a bad path element, then it should be a 404, as the URI (path) can not be found.

*But*, if you really, really want to do the validation instead (and get a 400), RESTEasy also has [Bean Validation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.6.0.Final/userguide/html/Validation.html) support. Please do not use this. Follow good REST practices.

Comment: Thx Paul, is Bean Validation not only for POST-Requests?

Comment: Why do you think it's only for POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

Paul's solution is elegant

Still if you want validation on method parameters, you can do something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{docId}")
public SomeThing getSomeThing(@IsNumeric @PathParam("docId") String docId) {
   return ...;
}
```